# Append a div just below the particular clicked div in a multiple

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend

[image]

I have this list . Now when i click on any particular element , a box should be rendered just below that particular row
I need to wrap elements in such a way that rest of the rows are shifted down .
Is there any plugin available ?

Render method of InvestmentList

```
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <ul className="panel-list list-inline">
      {this.state.list.length > 0 ?
        this.state.list.map((item,index)=>{
          /*if(!(item.type.toLowerCase()==='stock' && item.is_sold_once==false))*/
            return (
              <li key={index}>
                <div className="layout layout-1 fade-transition clearfix">
                  <div className="layout-header">
                    <div className="layout-img-ls">
                        <img src='https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/waccal/static+icons/layout_50.png' />
                    </div>
                    <div className="layout-img-text pull-right">
                      <p >asas</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="layout-content">
                      <h5>asasas</h5>
                      <a href="#">@adsd</a>
                  </div>
                  <div className="layout-footer">
                    <div className="dropdown">
                        <div className="wbtn-connected fade-transition"></div>
                        <i className="material-icons md-18 pull-right dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">more_vert</i>
                        <ul className="dropdown-menu wcl-sub-dropdown" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                          <li><a href="#">Sold</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Remove</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className=''>
                </div>
              </li>
            )
          })
      : <div> No Search Results. <img src="img/noresult.emoji.png" className="emoji-img"/></div>}
    </ul>

  </div>
);
```

}
This is the parent div

```
        <h5 className="wcl-main-heading">INVESTMENTS</h5>
        <div className="wcl-panel">
          <div className="wcl-panel-head">
            <span className="text-left heading-wcpanel">CURRENT</span>
             <button className="wcl-icon wcl-icon-gray popup-btn pull-right wcl-tooltip" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_investor"  data-placement="bottom" title="ADD" onClick={()=>{
                this.setState({
                  showAddInvestor:true
                })
             }}>
                <i className="material-icons md-18" >add_circle_outline</i>
            </button>
          </div>
          <InvestmentList list = {this.props.investors} setInvestor={this.setInvestor} showInvestor={this.showInvestor}/>
          <AddInvestor markSold = {false} showAddInvestor={this.state.showAddInvestor} closeModal={this.closeModal}/>
      </div>

      {this.state.showInvestor?
        <InvestmentInDetail showInvestor={this.showInvestor} investor={this.state.investor}/>
      :null}
    </div>
```

InvestmentList is the component which gets rendered after all the rows

[image]

Comment: Currently My new div  is rendered  after all the rows .  I need to render just after that particular row

Comment: did you miss adding the logic which adds the div's on click.. ?

Comment: @RajshekarReddy added

Comment: maybe you can add a "new div row x" after each row with the css property display:none. Then make it display:block when item in row x is clicked

Comment: @Nomistake As you can see in the code , <li> element is used which is repeated 
so how do i know which element clicked belongs to which row

Comment: @YashSharma with a loop ore something you can make each element from a certain row have an action to show the hidden box.
when a new row is started, this points to the box at the and of this new row and so on...

Comment: I'm not sure from your question exactly how your code ends up looking, but something roughly like this in jquery should work `$('li').eq(numLiInRows+$('li').index($(this))).after(newElementToInsert);`

Comment: @gaynorvader can you explain what exactly you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: It should add the `newElementToInsert` in a grid of li elements, below the clicked on li elements where the number of li in each row is `numLiInRows`

Comment: Here's a rough fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/unjj6b81/ Again, not sure if this is what you're asking for

Comment: @gaynorvader The width of the new div has to be 100% . Basically not part of that list

Comment: @gaynorvader As you can see the last screenshot attached , 
the whole new component is rendered below the clicked <li> element

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144851/discussion-between-gaynorvader-and-yash-sharma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, the solution is not too complicated (comments with explanations inline):

### JS

```
/*Populating ul with li*/
    for(var i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        $('ul').append('<li>' + (i+1) + '</li>');
    }
    /*Divide ul inner width by li outerwidth+margins to get number of li that fit on a single line*/
    var numLiInRows = $('ul').width() / $('ul').find('li').outerWidth(true);

    /*on needs to be used as the li are not present when the DOM was loaded*/
    $('ul').on('click','li', function(){
        $('ul').find('.info').remove();//remove previous info boxes
        var newElementToInsert = '<div class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>';//what the info box will be
      var liIndex = $('ul').find('li').index($(this));//find the position the clicked on li has in the array of li elements
      var numLi = $('ul').find('li').length;//find total li elements
      var row = Math.ceil((liIndex+1)/numLiInRows);//get row by using the index divided by how many li are in a row, rounded up
      console.log(row);

      /*if row times number of li in a row is bigger than the total li, just add the box after the last row*/
      if(row*numLiInRows >= numLi){
        $('ul').find('li').eq(numLi-1).after(newElementToInsert);
      }
      /*Add the box after the . end of the current row*/
      else{             
        $('ul').find('li').eq(row*numLiInRows-1).after(newElementToInsert);
       }
    });
```

### CSS

```
ul{
  width: 480px;
  list-style: none;
}
li{
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}
.info{
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/unjj6b81/1/)